# Framework for sync offline Mobile data to server to cloud in React native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, synchronization

I am developing a Mobile App and targeted platforms are iOS and Android. Mobile App fetches data from cloud and user can view and edit. User is allowed view and edit data even in offline mode(When Mobile is not connected to internet). 
Tech stack is as below:

**Mobile App**:
React Native (Cross platform)

**Cloud**:
C#, .Net and MS SQL

Please suggest a framework/library that synchronises (offline edited data) Mobile data to cloud.